# How to use string in JS replace() parameter

Tags: javascript, html, string

i need use string `replace(string , string);`in javascript I can use string here but simply, i need use "/" slash before string and i need use "/g" after string. Because i need replace all. Sorry for my English.

Exapmle :  replace(/string/g,'');

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">

var nesne ;
if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { nesne = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); }
else { nesne = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
var oku;
var okua;
var okub;
var a;
var b;
var c;
var okuc;

var al;
function yolla() {
oku = document.getElementById('dosya').value;
okua = document.getElementById('karak').value;
okub = document.getElementById('degis').value;
a = "/";
b = '/g';
c = "|";
okuc = a.concat(okua, b);
nesne.open('get', oku, true); 
nesne.onreadystatechange= cevap;
nesne.send(null);
}

function cevap() {
if(nesne.readyState==4) {
var el = document.getElementById('bilgi');

//el.innerHTML = nesne.responseText;
var al = nesne.responseText;

//el.innerHTML = al.replace(/#|_/g,'');
el.innerHTML = al.replace(okuc,'');
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Dosya Adi" name="" id="dosya">
<input type="text" placeholder="Degistirilecekler" name="" id="karak">
<input type="text" placeholder="ne ile değişsinler" name="" id="degis">
<input type="button" value="Dosyayı Oku"  onclick="yolla()">

<div id="bilgi"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a way to dynamically create a regular expression. You can do that with the [`RegExp` constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
okuc = new RegExp(okua, 'g');
```

Don't concatenate your search string with `/` and `/g`. That's wrong.